# Is there a way to find out every resource that calls a lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that gets called from several place through out an large app. Is there a way to discover every resource that is calling/using/attached to that lambda?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check from where lambda is calling/using/attached you can check it form designer in lambda.

Dashboard of lambda having designer that show lambda is connected with API Gateway , alexa skill etc.

So you can check everything from designer of lambda although you can also use cloud formation stack if you have made it for lambda.

[image]

> Here Lambda is connected with cloud watch and amazon EC2

There should be api gateway and other component also